# Adding hover effect to child divs not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I want to add a MouseOver effect for all my child items in my `parentDiv`. But now if I hover my mouse over one of those squares always the last of my `childDivs` actually changes its background, no matter on which child I place my mouse. Why is that?

```
for (let i = 0; i < Number(height); i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < Number(width); j++)
        {                               
            var childDiv = document.createElement("div");
            childDiv.className = "childDiv";
            childDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";
            childDiv.id = `${i};${j}`
            childDiv.onclick = () => childDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            childDiv.onmouseenter = () => childDiv.style.background = "#cccccc";                
            childDiv.onmouseleave = () => childDiv.style.background = "#e6e6e6";
            parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv); 
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change var to let:

```
let childDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4u93gmky/). And here is more info about differences between [var and let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav) (in short `var childDiv` is create once on first iteration (and visible outside for loops) and at the last iteration its value is set to last item -  each arrow function ()=>{} use that `childDiv` and its last value after loop execution ; `let childDiv` is created on each iteration "separately" (it is not visible outside for loop) and pass to arrow functions ) .